# How to Specify playback start time in Android

Tags: android, jwplayer

I'm using JwPlayer and found that version 3.13.0 is giving exceptions of player. So, i decided to use 3.12.1 version it self.

now i want to start the video from where user has left watching the video.

So, i found this https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/android-specify-playback-start-time

but it is only for  `3.13.0` or higher versions. And for older version their is no docs.

So, How to Specify playback start time in JwPlayer 3.12.1 and below for Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This Function

```
public void seek_forward(View view) {
        mPlayerView.seek(mPlayerView.getPosition()+3);
    }
```

- mPlayerView.getPosition() is for getting current position. From current position only you need to seek forward.

Answer (score 1):

Pre 3.13, the closest thing would be to listen for onPlay and seek forward to whatever time you want to start at.

If you're experiencing issues with a crash you can reach out to support at https://support.jwplayer.com/submit-support-case

Comment: got it but i stuck here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61743763/how-to-customize-jwplayer-in-android